# Power Dissipation Issues

Tags: circuit-analysis

I built a circuit with a 5V power supply and a 300-ohm resistor. With a multimeter I did the measurements of resistance, voltage, and current across the resistor. The values were:

\$R = 298 \mathrm{\Omega} \$

\$E = 4.94 \mathrm{V}\$

\$I  = 16 \mathrm{mA}\$

So I made the calcs to obtain the power dissipated by the resistor:

\$P = EI = 4.94 \cdot 0.016 = 79 \mathrm{mW} \$

\$P = \dfrac{E^2}{R} = \dfrac{4.94^2}{298} = 81.9 \mathrm{mW} \$

\$P = I^2 \cdot R = 0.016^2 \cdot 298 = 76.3 \mathrm{mW}\$

My question is: Why there are differences between the power results? It's because of the lack of precision in measurements, the increase of resistor's resistance when powered or a combination of both?

Comment: whether all measurements are right....there should be some thing hidden..How you calculated current through resistor?

Comment: Rounding errors. 0.016 could mean 0.0155 or 0.0165.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's partly the precision of your measurements, and partly the effects of the meter you were using.

When you measured the voltage, you put the meter in parallel with the resistor and measured 4.94 volts, which is the value that your power supply is producing.

When you measured the current, you put the meter in series with the resistor, and measured 16 milliamps. However, the voltage across the resistor at this time was NOT exactly 4.94 volts, because the meter necessarily requires a voltage drop in order to measure current. This drop can be as much as 200 mV on most meters (at full scale), but in any case, it's proportional to the reading. In this case, your meter was probably causing a voltage drop of either 1.6 mV or 16 mV, depending on the measurement range you selected.

What this means is that the resistor was indeed dissipating slightly less power during the current measurement, because the voltage across it was slightly reduced. This explains why the calculation based on the current measurement alone is the lowest and the calculation based on the voltage measurement alone is the highest. The calculation based on the voltage and current together falls in the middle, because it is basically an average of the other two power levels.

Answer (score 5):

What difference?  I don't see a difference.

79 = 81.9 (±3.5%).  Note that there are three separate measurements involved, and one of them is squared.  76.3 is a bit lower, but also note that it is a function of three measurements (resistance, and current twice).  You'd expect the current measurement to be a little low because there was some inevitable voltage drop across the meter, so the voltage on the resistor was less, and the current therefore less than when the meter is not in series with the resistor.

The current measurement being a little low, and the other measurements being within reasonable tolerance seems to explain things.  Look up how accurate your meter reports resistance, for example.

Another way to look at this is to use two of the measured values to derive the other, then compare to the actual measured value.  For example, (4.94 V)/(16 mA) = 309 Ω.  The resistor says 300 Ω, you measure 0.7% low directly, and compute 3% high.  Again, where is the discrepancy?  Note that your current measurement of "16 mA" has 3.1% error built just numerically, and that's not accounting for the inherent measurement error I mentioned above.

There is no discrepancy here.

Comment: You're right. I think the problem is the lack of precision in my measurement of current. My multimeter is not so good.